# Is it possible to make a bot in discord.js search for previous messages without a json,or having to store it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Basically like the search function in discord.

For example if I want to make a

!search [user] [query]

and make it respond

"50 messages fit the query"

a word counter bot without the db or local storage basically.[The bot would return 87 on this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvWWy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sadly. Here's why...

## Explanation

---

Message query is limited to user accounts.
There's a lot of ways to do the workaround but the best way and most used is to fetch a large amount of messages in the specific channel.

---

#### Fetching all messages?

All endpoints that are related to fetching always have a limit of 100 things per request.
 Fetching messages? 100 messages per request. etc. etc.
There's no way to bypass this, and the only solution is to fetch and re-fetch and re-fetch until you reached certain amount.

---

#### Demonstration

```js
// Fetch a 100 messages from a Channel
// You can always fetch more and concat() the collections together
// <Channel> is a placeholder for guild's text-based channels
const messages = await <Channel>.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });

// Make a filter
// In this case, we're finding messages with "hello". Case insensitive
const query = (msg) => msg.content.toLowerCase().includes("hello");

// Filter out non-matching messages
const matching = messages.filter(query);


console.log(matching);
// `matching` is Collection<Snowflake, Message>
```